# How to wait for promises to be resolved

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I have created a function `verifyIfUserIsInGame(userId)` that allows checking if the user given as argument is in game. This function searches the Firebase database and returns true or false. (so it is a promise within the function).

I would now like to check, once the function has been executed for 2 users if they are in play. 
I'm not very comfortable with promises. I made this code but it doesn't work since I get `[object Promise]` in the console logs.

```
  // We check that both users are in this game
  user1IsInGame = verifyIfUserIsInGame(user1Id); // must return true or false
  user2IsInGame = verifyIfUserIsInGame(user2Id); // must return true or false

  console.log("user1: " + user1IsInGame);
  console.log("user2: " + user2IsInGame);

  if (userIsInGame && user2IsInGame) {
    // The users are in game
  } else {
    // The users are not in game
  }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "*and returns true or false. (so it is a promise within the function).*" - do you mean that it returns a promise for the boolean?

Comment: No, I explained myself wrong: the async function simply returns true or false.

Comment: Well your code demonstrates that it doesn't, the call returns a promise. Which is good, an asynchronous function cannot immediately return the boolean value that it will receive in the future.

Comment: Yes I understood correctly, but I don't know how to manage promises: async/await doesn't work

Comment: `Promise.all([verifyIfUserIsInGame(user1Id), verifyIfUserIsInGame(user2Id)]).then(([user1IsInGame, user2IsInGame]) => { if (user1IsInGame && user2IsInGame) { … } else { … } });`

Comment: Your solution sounds good, but when I execute the function, I get an error (it executes .catch)

Comment: Here is my code, and so I always get the error : "error is not defined" in the console logs --> https://pastebin.com/gmWHXWTQ

Comment: That makes no sense. You're not using `error` in the code you've shown to us anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, you can use `Promise.all`, but none of the other answers had any content in your verify function, so just wanted to provide a full example.

This is one way of doing it, you can ofc change the resolve to just pass true/false back and then change the if statements.

```js
function verifyIfUserIsInGame(user_id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({ id: user_id, inGame: true });
  });
}

// run this when all checks have been performed.
function callbackFunction(players){

  let playersReady = 0;
  players.forEach(player => {
    if(player.inGame){
      console.log(`player ${player.id} are in the game`);
      playersReady++;
    }
  });
  if(playersReady === players.length){
    console.log("All players are in the game");
  }
  
}


// the checks we want to perform
const verifyAllUsers = [
  verifyIfUserIsInGame(1),
  verifyIfUserIsInGame(2)
];

// wait for promises to finish.
Promise.all(verifyAllUsers)
       .then( users => callbackFunction(users) )
       .catch( err => console.error(err) );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `async` and `await` to achieve asynchronity.

```js
async function verifyIfUserIsInGame() {
  //the content of your function
  return true;
}


async function func() {
  // We check that both users are in this game
  const user1IsInGame = await verifyIfUserIsInGame(user1Id); // must return true or false
  const user2IsInGame = await verifyIfUserIsInGame(user2Id); // must return true or false

  console.log("user1: " + user1IsInGame);
  console.log("user2: " + user2IsInGame);

  if (userIsInGame && userToKillIsInGame) {
    // The users are in game
  } else {
    // The users are not in game
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I add async before a function : [eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token function

Comment: @Jean That probably means you should fix your eslint settings, not avoid async/await syntax.

Comment: @Bergi No, it's just that Firebase Function doesn't support async/await.

Comment: Then you could use `Promise.all()` which takes an array of promises and returns a promise which resolves when all passed promises have resolved

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel This was Bergi's proposal above (under my post), but it doesn't work too. I always get the error : "error is not defined" in the console logs --> pastebin.com/gmWHXWTQ

Comment: In which line? And without the .catch() ?

Answer (score 0):

Just `await` the promises maybe? :

```
 (async function() {
    const user1IsInGame = await verifyIfUserIsInGame(user1Id); // must return true or false
    const user2IsInGame = await verifyIfUserIsInGame(user2Id); // must return true or false

    console.log("user1: " + user1IsInGame);
    console.log("user2: " + user2IsInGame);

     if (userIsInGame && userToKillIsInGame) {
       // The users are in game
     } else {
       // The users are not in game
     }
 })()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all if you want to run two functions simultaneously:

```
  (async function() {
    const usersAreInGame = await Promise.all(verifyIfUserIsInGame(user1Id), 
                                            verifyIfUserIsInGame(user2Id)); 

     if (usersAreInGame[0] && usersAreInGame[1]) {
       // The users are in game
     } else {
       // The users are not in game
     }
 })()
```